# Filtering data based on username

Tags: grails, groovy

The domain class 'Message' displayed below:

```
String name
String age
User user
```

From the following code, i retrieve all the messages that was posted. But what i really want is to display is all messages of a particular user. For example : user.firstName. How can i do it?

```
def messages = Message.listOrderByDate(order: 'asc', max:1000)

println messages.firstName + " BOOOOOOO "

[messages:messages.reverse()]
```

So instead of displaying all the data i want to filter the data based on users name. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be queried in the following way:

```
def results = Message.withCriteria {
  user {
    eq("name", theUserNameYouWantToQuery)
  }
  order("date", "asc")
  maxResults(1000)
}
```

This example could be extended to grouping etc. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Answer (score 0):

create as hasMany relationship from user to Message like this:

```
class User {
  static hasMany = [messages: Message]
}

class Message{
  String name
  String age
  static belongsTo [user: User]
}
```

and then use `myUser.messages` to fetch all Messages from this user.